# pyplot.savefig() Memory Leak inside a loop python

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, memory-management, memory-leaks

I am plotting Bar graphs and saving the graph as .png using plt.savefig()

Here is the code :-

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('agg')

import matpltlib.pyplot as plt 

Plot_Value = [[13,6],[4,3],[6,8]]
x_axis = ["r1","r2"]
loop_value = ["L 1","L 2","L 3"]
for i in range(len(loop_value)):

        fig = plt.figure()
        plt.xticks(range(1, len(x_axis) + 1), x_axis,rotation=30)
        plt.yticks(range(max(Plot_Value[i]) + 4))
        BAR = plt.bar([x + 1 for x in range(len(x_axis))],Plot_Value[i])
        fig.suptitle('SAVEFIG EXAMPLE', fontsize=20)
        plt.xlabel('X-AXIS', fontsize=15)
        plt.ylabel('Y-AXIS', fontsize=15)

        for rect in  BAR:
            height = rect.get_height()
            plt.text(rect.get_x() + rect.get_width()/2.0, height, '%d' % int(height), ha='center', va='bottom')

        plt.savefig(str(loop_value[i].split(' ')[0])+str(loop_value[i].split(' ')[1])+".png", bbox_inches = "tight")
        plt.close()
```

This code above is small code from a large python file.
Till this code is not active i have a constant memory usage for my python program. But as soon as this code gets active my memory shoots 35MB and this memory doesn't deallocate after plotting is over and program moves to other functions in file . This code has to be active many times and i cant afford these memory spikes every time it is executed.

I have used `plt.close(), plt.close('all'), plt.clf(), plt.cla()`

used `del fig` (which i know would not affect this problem)

Also tried `gc.collect()` after and inside loop nothing helped .

How can i solve this , or am i missing something .

Comment: Did you look at what part of code (more specifically which line) was causing this spike ? You could use `memory_profiler` and its line-by-line feature to observe.